# How do I put these AngularJS expressions into this specific table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm working on some AngularJS tutorials and one of the exercises is asking me to put these expressions into a table format that represents this image:

[image]

This here is my current set of expressions. I've tried using my own combination of   and  tags to organise it it into this specific image. But when I try to do it, the table ends up coming out wrong formatted and I'd just like to know what I'm doing wrong and how I can write it up to represent the image.

```
{{itinerary.itiName | date }}
{{itinerary.destination | date}}
{{itinerary.purpose | date}}
{{itinerary.startDate | date}}
{{itinerary.endDate | date}}
```

Can someone help me out here? Please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `ng-repeat` expression in table row should solve your problems. You already have the required data to push it to view.

Link to the ng-repeat doc is [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

In case you are facing a bug then please commit your codes here.